# get the closest value from a list jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to get the closest class html from my list, but its always returning null if i put directly the `closest`. i try some other thinks, but its not working.

the **html:**

```
<ul id="ulId">
  <li class='effectLeg'>
    Stuffs
  </li>
  <li class='test legColor' style=''></li>
  <li class='effectLeg'>
    Stuffs 2
  </li>
  <li class='test legColor'></li>
</ul>
```

so, if i hover the last LI (for exp.) the hover will get the closest class  `effectLeg` and give me the HTML or anything inside ( in that case the STUFFS 2 ).

the **js**:

```
$(".legColor").live("hover", function(){
    alert($(this).closest("#ulId").find(".effectLeg").html());
});
```

the closest i get was using find, but the find only get the first value of my `li`

i made a exp: check the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eC5YE/7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) searches the an element's ancestors, but it looks like you're trying to search the siblings. I think you just want [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev):

```
$(".legColor").live("hover", function(){
    console.log($(this).prev('li.effectLeg'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/nggyX/

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect ... Depending on what closest thing you are after you'd be doing:

```
alert($(this).closest("ul").html());
```

That would return the html of `#ulId`

Comment: `$(this).closest("ul")` will find the same element as `$(this).closest("#ulId")`.

Comment: like i say, if i hover the last LI (for exp.) the hover will get the closest class effectLeg and give me the HTML or anything inside ( in that case the STUFFS 2 ). i dont need the html of all ul